# Compare image in dalekjs

Tags: image, unit-testing, automation, dalekjs

I wanted to automate image comparison through dalekjs.  Aim is to have better image comparisons through external libraries but for starters a basic image comparison will do to tell if image on page is equal to local image.  Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Dalekjs doesn't give any native method to access image let alone compare them...  Only thing i can think of is somehow save image through Dom and compare it through js script...  Bt again the problem is to do it with dalek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still experimental and is yet to be merged into DalekJS core, but you could try using [gskachkov](https://github.com/gskachkov)'s pull request [here](https://github.com/dalekjs/dalek/pull/112) which adds screenshot comparison functionality to DalekJS.

Otherwise, I would recommend you to use [PhantomCSS](https://github.com/Huddle/PhantomCSS) as your visual regression framework for the time being. PhantomCSS is built on top of [CasperJS](http://github.com/n1k0/casperjs) and uses [Resemble.js](http://huddle.github.com/Resemble.js/) for image comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Dalek isn't designed to be used as an image comparison tool, but some people used it as a foundation to write their own tools, like [siteeffect.io](http://siteeffect.io/)

If you need to want to compare two images you need to make a screenshot with Dalek, need to know the coordinates of the image & then run some image comparison using Image Magick or whatever.

If you have some code/experiment up on GitHub or so, I´m happy to provide guidance to get the data out of Dalek & to use it programmatically.